# How do I use paired?

Tags: compound-adjectives

In the sentence "they've built roads, ports and stores in our city, but these facts are unpaired to the schooling steep growing levels."

I'd like to know two things:

1. Is the usage of "but these facts are unpaired" correct? Could I change it for "but none of these facts are paired"
2. Is "schooling steep growing levels" well structured?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want ***unconnected with*** rather than ***unpaired to***. But what on earth is *"schooling steep growing levels"* supposed to mean?

Comment: @Fumble, "*schooling steep growing levels*" most likely means "*the growth rate of schools*".

Comment: @Dan: Why bother guessing? Let the OP clarify, since he presumably *knows* what he means.

Comment: Ok, by "schooling steep growing levels" I meant that people have been studying much more, so the schooling levels are higher than before.

Comment: Do you mean there really ***is*** more education (but this has no connection to the fact that roads, ports, and stores have been built)? Or do you mean that the increased building/infrastructure ***has not been matched by a corresponding increase*** in educational provision/attainment?

Comment: I made a big confusion. My idea was to say that the fact that people have been studying for longer years is more important than having roads, ports and so on built.
But from your explanation I can see it has nothing to do with it, right?

So, how about if I would just make it "they've built roads, ports and stores in our city, but these facts are not as important as the fact that people have gotten a better education system"

Is that ok? It changes the meaning but I'm trying to make a clear sentence.

Comment: I fell like I now understand the usage of pair. It's used to associate things that can be associated, so when we say "unpaired with" it gives the idea that it can't be grouped, right?

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you are trying to say that you think that those "facts" SHOULD  be "paired" (or connected) with rising education levels? Or whether you want to suggest that other types of industry or technology would be more appropriate (to a more educated workforce)? Maybe you meant to say that such infrastructure projects are good, but do not REFLECT or UTILIZE (the increased abilities of a more educated populace)?  In any case, "paired" does not seem to make the point.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to say that better educated people are more important than better infrastructure?  But both are needed for the economy to grow.  I'd say something like:  "The economy of our city has grown because of investment in schools, roads and ports."   (the stores are part of the economy.)  Then you could go on to try to make the case that the schools were more important.  If there is a Stacks for economists, you might go there for advice.